# Why can an ASP.NET Core action returning an ` ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>>` return a `BadRequest()` of any object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I wonder why an ASP.NET Core action returning an `ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>>` may return a `BadRequest(scan)`, where `scan` is an object of a custom user-defined class?

In this case, I don't see any sensible way of converting `ZapScan` to `IEnumerable<ZapResult>`.

Indeed, both `Ok()` and `BadRequest()` return objects derived from `ActionResult` (not `ActionResult<T>`), but in either case everything works fine and JSON is returned to the client:

```
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>> OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
    return HandleRequest(scan);
}

private ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>> HandleRequest(ZapScan scan)
{
    if (ValidateScan(scan)) {
        IEnumerable<ZapResult> zapResults = _zapDispatcher.Dispatch(scan);
        return Ok(zapResults);
    }
    else
    {
        var clientIp = HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        var requestUrl = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(HttpContext.Request);
        _logger.LogError("{0}: Invalid request: [{1}] {2} ({3})", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, clientIp, requestUrl, scan);
        return BadRequest(scan);
    }
}
```

To me it seems like anything can be converted to `ActionResult<T>`, and that such return type is completely generic?

Comment: It should be able to convert it `ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>>`. I am a bit confused with your end result requirement.

Comment: @panoskarajohn - `ZapScan` is not a `IEnumerable<ZapResult>`, so why can I return `BadRequest(scan)` from a method with a return type of `ActionResult<IEnumerable<ZapResult>>`?

Answer (score 1):

`BadRequestResult` (returned by `BadRequest()`) derives from `ActionResult`.
`ActionResult<T>` is implicitly convertible to `ActionResult` (via the `IConvertToActionResult` interface it implements).

Therefore the return types are compatible which is why they can be used interchangeably.

`BadRequestResult` has a constructor that takes any `object` and serializes it to a string that is output as-is to the client.

Comment: Why is it sensible to have such conversion from `ActionResult<T>` to `IActionResult` (not `ActionResult`)? Also, although `ActionResult<T>` is converted to `IActionResult`, the return types in my methods are still `ActionResult<T>` - not `IActionResult` ...? :-)